# Items are not adding to vector c++

Tags: c++

```
 class Way {
private:
    std::vector<Node> nodesCollection; 
public:
    Way();
    Way(const Way& orig);
    virtual ~Way();

    void SetNodesCollection(std::vector<Node> nodesCollection);
    std::vector<Node> GetNodesCollection() const;
};
```

I added vector as a property and I'm accessing that vector from following class and adding items.

```
Way wayNode;

 for (; WayIter!=wayNodes.end(); ++WayIter)
{
    const JSONNode& arrayNode = *WayIter;
    if (arrayNode.find("ref") != arrayNode.end() )
    {
        std::string id = arrayNode.find("ref")->as_string();

        if(nodesMap.find(id) != nodesMap.end())
        {
            wayNode.GetNodesCollection().push_back(nodesMap.find(id)->second);
        }
    }
}
```

but items are not adding to "nodesCollection". its count is zero. that adding object is not null.

I need some help to sort out this. I'm new to c++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is wayNodes? It has appeared mysteriously in your code snippet...

Comment: its a JSONNode , that "nodesMap.find(id)->second" is not null.

Comment: Node or rather some container of Nodes? Please pay more attention to what you show and what you say. Note: wayNodes. s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about [pass by value vs pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).  GetNodesCollection is returning a brand new copy of the vector.  Then you add your nodes to this new copy, instead of to the original.

Well, maybe it is more [return by value vs return by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/).  Anyway the point is that you are getting a brand new copy instead of a reference to the original vector.

One way to fix would be to change the return type to a reference (you'd have to make the same change where GetNodesCollection is defined)

```
std::vector<Node>& GetNodesCollection();
```

Comment: the method is declared as part of class Way in the first listing?

Comment: method implementation 
std::vector<Node>& Way::GetNodesCollection() const {
    return nodesCollection;
}
but its getting an error

Comment: yes, so when you push_back now it will actually write to the vector within your Way object, so it shoudl not stay empty

Comment: ah - you will have to remove the 'const' from the implementation (since you want to modify a member of the object)